# How to use one select query to return a restructured table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

For example, I have this table:

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| name | length | width | status | side  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| T1   | 5      | 2     | DONE   | Left  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| T1   | 2      | 1     | DONE   | Right |
+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

But need one select query to return:

```
 +------+-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| name | left_length | left_width | left_status | right_length | right_width | right_status |
+------+-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| T1   | 5           | 2          | DONE        | 2            | 1           | DONE         |
+------+-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

What is this kind of operation called?
I'm using Postgres.

Comment: You can use the conditional aggregation solution provided in the answer, or you can install the tablefunc module and use the crosstab function, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Comment: Thanks for the terminology. I had no idea what to look-up. I see I have much to read now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
    max(case when side = 'Left' then length end) as left_length,
    max(case when side = 'Left' then width end) as left_width,
    max(case when side = 'Left' then status end) as left_status,
    max(case when side = 'Right' then length end) as right_length,
    max(case when side = 'Right' then width end) as right_width,
    max(case when side = 'Right' then status end) as right_status
from your_table
group by name;
```